# Juju-Gui Charm API did not respond

Tags: juju

After deploying juju-gui, It isn't able to communicate with the Charm API for some reason. 
When looking into the Chrome debugger I get errors like 
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://manage.jujucharms.com/api/2/charms?text=nod&autocomplete=true&limit=5. Origin https://ec2-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

manage.jujucharms.com is undergoing some updates right now so this issue will resolve itself once that's finished. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Edit: Back up!

Comment: Hey, I just downloaded it to test so no worries about back-ups. Now it doesnt even go in at all and I see the following error : "WebSocket connection to 'wss://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ws' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established."

Comment: Typically that means that you are behind a firewall or proxy that doesn't allow the secure websocket to be upgraded. This will be easier to debug on IRC, feel free to pop into #juju on irc.freenode.net if you aren't able to get it solved.